# Prevent SwiftUI NavigationLink inheriting overridden preferredColorScheme

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a view that spawns a child view via NavigationLink. I want this parent view to always display in dark mode, and children to display with the system's colour scheme:

```swift
struct ParentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      HStack {
        NavigationLink("Spawn child", destination: ChildView())
      }
    }.navigationBarHidden(true).preferredColorScheme(.dark)
  }
}

struct ChildView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("Some text")
  }
}
```

From what I've seen, the child views spawned by NavigationLink inherit the overridden colour scheme. Is there a way to allow the child views to inherit the system colour scheme instead?

[edit]

A sample project can be found here: https://filebin.net/2rvhy7a6wzjdhsgr/NavigationTest.zip?t=qffbi52b

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
struct ParentView: View {
  @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme   // top env color scheme
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      HStack {
        NavigationLink("Spawn child", destination:
            ChildView().colorScheme(colorScheme))  // << pass here !!
//            ChildView().preferredColorScheme(colorScheme))  // << alternate 
      }.preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }.navigationBarHidden(true)
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work, the child view still displays in dark mode

Comment: I've tweaked my sample code a bit. I'm working with Xcode 12 / iOS 14. On iOS 13 I've noticed that my original code was displaying the parent view as the system colour, whereas on iOS 14 it overrides it properly. I've adjusted it to have the same behaviour on iOS 13 by changing the preferred colour on the navigation view itself. With the new sample code above, it doesn't work.

Comment: Tested with Xcode 12b3 - if instead of `preferredColorScheme(.dark)` use in same place `.colorScheme(.dark)` the behavior is the same as on iOS 13. Otherwise the behavior is incorrect, because applies .dark to entire screen, however must only to HStack.